# index page is not loading

Tags: errors, wp-enqueue-style

```
anndoe
|
|-------css/ anndoe.css
|-------js/anndoe.js
|--functions.php
|--header.php
|--index.php
|--style.css
```

I added below code to functions.php, and my index page doesn't show up. iF I remove this code my index page works.

```
<?php

function anndoe_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style ('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/anndoe.css','1.0.0','all');
}

add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'anndoe_script_enqueue')
```

In my header.php I added `<?php wp_head(); ?>` above `</head>` tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on your add_action.

Comment: you are right. `add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'anndoe_script_enqueue');`